# Create a "Task rabbit"-like in iOS

Tags: ios, rotation

Any expert please help me, I've been struggling with this one for days. I'm implementing the rotary wheel control (which I found on the internet) but I need to make it spin while user swipe on the screen, it should spin fast then slowing down and stop (as the app **Task rabbit** does).

I successfully created the wheel and make it spin, but it comes with another problem, let me show you my code

```
- (void)playRotationAnimation:(NSNumber*) _initialVelocity{
    double currentVelocity = ([self doubleAbs:[_initialVelocity doubleValue]])/10;
    while (currentVelocity > 0.1 && self.isRotatingWheel) {
        currentVelocity -= currentVelocity * 0.1;
        double netRotation = currentVelocity;
        if([_initialVelocity doubleValue] < 0) netRotation *= -1;
        NSNumber *_rotation = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((netRotation * M_PI) / 180)];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(rotateWheelView:) withObject:_rotation waitUntilDone:YES];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.07];
    }
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(animationStopped) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

and the animationStopped method is

```
- (void)rotateWheelView:(NSNumber *)_rotation {
    double rotation = [_rotation doubleValue];
    container.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(container.transform, rotation);
    NSLog(@"%g", rotation);
}
```

Ok, here is the idea: the "playRotationAnimation" will make the wheel keep scrolling until the currentVelocity reaches a limit, the wheel will scroll based on angle which is the velocity.

The problem is that when I swipe, first, it spins very well, then suddenly, it scrolls backward. For example, it's spinning clockwise for a while, suddenly it changes the direction and spin counterclockwise.

I hope someone can help me to solve this case :(